# Flip CCMenuItemImage?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2d, I can use the flipX property on CCSprites. But I don't seem to be able to do it with CCMenuItemImages... is it possible? Or do I have to use an already flipped image resource?

Answer (score 1):

you cant flip the image that is added to the `CCMenuItemImage`. I would recommend using `CCMenuItemSprite` instead. In that case you can easily get the sprite added to the `CCMenuItemSprite` and flip it:

```
CCMenuItemSprite *menuItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:normalSprite selectedSprite:selectedSprite target:self selector:@selector(aSelector)];
```

then when you want to access the sprite:

```
CCSprite *someSprite = [menuItem normalImage];
[someSprite flipX];
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

KDaker had the right idea, but the implementation wasn't quite right. Here is the code that I got to work:

```
CCSprite *normalSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"yourNormalButton.png"];
CCSprite *selectedSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"yourSelectedButton.png"];
normalSprite.flipX = TRUE;
selectedSprite.flipX = TRUE;

CCMenuItemSprite *menuItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:normalSprite selectedSprite:selectedSprite target:self selector:@selector(aSelector)];
```